# Why does Lightroom 4 not have chromatic aberration sliders?

Tags: lightroom-4, chromatic-aberration

I've upgraded to version 4 and so far so good until I was to correct the chromatic aberration in one photo.  I like to shoot wide open with my normal lens and the [Canon 50mm f1.4](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-50mm-f-1.4-USM-Lens-Review.aspx) produces significant halation which i often like but not so much when it is mixed with chromatic aberration.

Long story short; i like to fine tune CA with the sliders as it gives me a lot of control and allows me to practically eliminate CA from the haliation.

Instead, Lightroom 4 has either a "defringe" (in manual mode) check mark which is fully automatic and does not seem to provide any manual fine tuning. (has no effect on CA in haliation areas)  There is a "Remove Chromatic Aberration" in the Profile lens correction mode but it can only be enabled when the lens profile is enabled and it also does nothing for photos taken with this particular lens (when haliation is combined with CA).

Why isn't there a separate set of sliders to control CA anymore? What's the reasoning behind this?  I understand automation makes it easier in some cases but the exclusion of manual control does not seem to make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Lightroom 4 is a huge win if you have Chromatic Aberration. However, it addresses the problem differently than previous versions and in fact, than most other tools.

Scroll down to the Lens Corrections panel, and click on "Color". Then check the "Remove Chromatic Aberration" checkbox. This alone may help. However, you can dial it in: What sort of CA do you want to remove? I just processed an image with the dreaded purple fringing. So, I slid the top Amount slider up a ways, then took the eyedropper and clicked on the fringe. Presto. Gone.

The blue/yellow slider works pretty much the same way. You just have to play with it and make sure you've backed the amount down to the lowest acceptable setting so you don't compromise other parts of your image.

Here's a before/after of the image:

[image]

Side note: I just tried this on a Holga image shot on Portra film and scanned, just to make sure Lightroom would not have any lens info, and all the controls are still present. I'm not sure why you would be missing any of the sliders.

Comment: Thanks. I had those sliders in version 3.6 but not in version 4.0. (64 bit) Yes, i am wanting to remove purple/red and yellow fringing. As i said in the question I only have the check-mark but not the sliders.

Answer (score 3):

Lightroom [version 4.1](http://blogs.adobe.com/lightroomjournal/2012/05/lr41nowavailable.html) has new chromatic aberration options including sliders.

Answer (score 1):

Lightroom 4 does have sliders for fixing some types of CA, but the sliders for fixing red and blue fringing (which I assume is the type of CA you are having problems with) have been removed.

The 'Remove Chromatic Aberration' checkbox (under Lens Corrections > Color in the Develop module) is now meant to automatically remove this type of CA and is supposed to work without a lens profile available.

The [Lightroom 4 Missing FAQ](http://www.lightroomqueen.com/books/adobe-lightroom-4-missing-faq/) says that you can try using the Moire removal setting on the Adjustment Brush to remove residual CA that the other tools can't remove.